# how to install ipad air simulator on xcode 5.0.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator, xcode5

can anyone tell me  how to install iPad air simulator using Xcode 5.0.1?i have tried to search for a solution but didn't  find any solution,and i would like to know  is iPad retina and iPad air both are same,please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specially Simulator for iPad air,
because its rendering 1536 x 2048 pixels resolution, so in old ipad 2 Retina simulator you can test.

Answer (score 0):

iPad retina simulator and the simulator for iPad Air, both are same. Since, iPad Air has Retina display.

No need to search any new simulator for iPad Air.